# How to remove previous layer when draw new?

Tags: leaflet

Current behaviour of Draw plugin is add every new drawing layer to the map:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'marker') {
        // Do marker specific actions
    }

    // Do whatever else you need to. (save to db, add to map etc)
    map.addLayer(layer);
});
```

but how to improve this code to get it remove every previous layer when user draw new one? I can't understand how to call: `map.removeLayer(layer);` and say it that I want to remove previous, but not current layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove **all** layers on map, you could use a code similar to that one at the beginning of your `"draw:created"` event listener:

```js
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  map.removeLayer(layer);
});
```

(but I think that would also remove your Tile Layers, so maybe you should add some checks in there)

Should you use an intermediate `drawnItems` Feature Group, you could also simply use the [`.clearLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-clearlayers) method:

```js
drawnItems.clearLayers();
```

Comment: what type I should to check during `map.eachLayer` ?

Comment: Probably something like `layer !== myTileLayer`. But I would recommend using a Feature Group, so that you can simply clear everything in that Group.

Comment: Could you show example of it's usage. I can't even understand how to use `Feature Group` to adding data. The link above looks not about it.

Comment: I mean using `drawnItem` to store your newly created layers (replace `map.addLayer(layer)` by `drawnItem.addLayer(layer)`) so that you can then do `drawnItems.clearLayers()` when you want to remove all previously created layers, as shown in the last part of my above answer